# Animated show about teens controlling monsters virtually

Tags: story-identification, tv, animated-series

It's a mix of 3D/2D animation. I saw it around the early 2000s, I think.

I remember an episode where one of the main characters' devices breaks in the monster's world and they have to survive with another monster while the main character is not a monster and human, until his friends and other people can find a way to bring him back to their world.

I'm not sure what the show is called, but I know it's not *Chaotic*, *Digimon* or *Bakugan*.

Comment: How did the teens control the monsters? Did they use cards? Handheld devices? Devices worn around their wrists? Also, did the teen just control monsters, or could they transform into monsters as well? And can you describe what any of the main characters looked like?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.